# What is the downside of using a filter as a "poor man's" dependency injection?

Tags: filters, oop

First of all, I don't know whether or not "dependency injection" is the right term to use, what would be "dependencies" in my case are really objects that I use within other "parent".

I have a big importing system, where, for each step that can be imported (each step deals with importing a certain part of the site), the said step has some objects (that each deal with specific parts of the whole importing process, be it the actual import, the "make sure it looks good" and the cleaning process) attached to it.

I decided that, at the beginning of the lifecycle of each WP load, I'll store these in a filter:

```
    add_filter('steps_objects_map', function( $objects ) {
        $objects= [
            'customizer' => [
                'importer' => new ImportCustomizer,
                'bridge' => new CustomizerBridge,
                'cleaner' => new CustomizerCleaner,
            ],
        ];
        return $objects;
    });
```

The system is written in such a way that you can use these objects that we provide as a baseline for your work but you can also choose to not use them, the sytem was built so that **even if you modify these objects totally or just simply use a new one along the other old ones, it still works**.

In short, my main controllers don't care about what you do individually, they'll tell you about good things to do and bad things to do, but it's up to you what you do, as such, the system does not care, at all, about your low-level implementations, it just enforces certain rulesets per interfaces whose functions take certain objects as parameters to ensure that your data, between each of these steps objects looks the same so that when my controllers look for it, it's not missing.

In short, the rules you must adhere to are very light and are there to protect you - **but:**

I also want to give you freedom, as initially said, to use your own objects. But, let's assume, for a second that, say, your `cleaner` object that is called when you want to remove the component uses the `import`, for some reason. What you'd normally do is, at the top of your `CustomizerCleaner`, you would `use ImportCustomizer`:

```
--CustomizerCleaner.php:
use Namespace\ImportCustomizer;

class CustomizerCleaner implements CleanerInterface {
    public function clean( $arg, $arg1 )
    {
        $importer = new ImportCustomizer;
    }
}
```

And there's the issue. That hardcoded `ImportCustomizer` can never change now, unless the original file changes itself, but then you're also stuck with that path itself. What if you want to have something else, from a plugin? Maybe you decided to have a "Improve Framework" package over my original core, you can't now because it's all hardcoded.

But because we're using a "main integration file" which any developer using my framework is free to edit and is the go-to thing to do for adapting my framework to your clients' needs and a filter, this flies like a plane.

Set it all up in an initial file, then forget it exists and just call whatever you need as follows:

```
apply_filters( 'step_objects_map', [] )['customizer']['importer'];
```

This will always be whatever you defined in that filter.

Plug in and out, just make sure you respect the few rules that are set by the interfaces and 99% of the system will do the heavylifting for you without punishment.

So what am I missing here? It seems that this is a silver bullet and I fail to see its downsides *besides the global state of a filter*.

Things to mention:

1) The `__construct` of each of these objects is empty and this is to avoid memory cluttering where an object could hold a lot of memory hostage through a big part of the lifespan of a WP request.

2) The framework will have a very specific use-case, if you mess up your system it's not the framework's fault, but yours for not respecting the clear-defined & easy-to-follow guidelines. In a way, the framework itself is bias-agnostic: it doesn't care what you do in your free time (these objects that it uses), but it cares that you have free time (you have these objects and their specific implementation).